# Use of past perfect

Tags: perfect-aspect

We’re having a discussion here on whether or not to use the past perfect in following sentence:

> The cargo was visible through the gap and was noted to have (had?) sustained damage.

Which is correct and why?

Answer (score 1):

The version without *had* is correct.

The perfect aspect in English is formed by using the auxiliary verb *have* (or for some verbs *be*) in the appropriate tense or construction, followed by the past participle of the main verb, in this case *sustain*.

More or less all constructions of the auxiliary verb are allowed in perfect constructions (even ones that mix in another aspect: progressiveness)—but not perfect constructions themselves. You can make present perfects, past perfects, future perfects, past subjunctive perfects, present progressive perfects, infinitive perfects, past progressive perfects, etc. But you cannot make a perfect perfect or a past perfect perfect.

In your case, *have had* is the infinitive perfect of *have*, while *have sustained* is the infinitive perfect of *sustain*. But **have had sustained* is an impossible perfect infinitive perfect.

Of course, if you intended “to have (had?)” to mean that you were considering “to had” a possibility, that is immediately rejected: this use of *to* marks an **infinitive**, and *had* is past tense. An infinitive marker on a past tense verb is always ungrammatical.

Answer (score 0):

The correct form is **have**!

This is beacause you are refering to an action and specifically after a **to**.

Statements like this always have an infinitive to point to the main action described.

Ex:

> Our English professor is said to be the oldest professor in the university.

Or:

> The market as some experts believe was claimed to have the best products when it was four years old.

Comment: There is a _have_ in the example already; _to have had_ is also an infinitive, just not one that can form part of a perfect construction. (Also, please use proper blockquoting on ELU, rather than indenting. It looks nicer.)

Answer (score 0):

*And was noted to have sustained damage* is correct. With the verb sustained, had is not necessary. Without the past tense verb *sustained* in the sentence, the auxiliary past tense verb *had* would be necessary to convey that the damage occurred in the past. In other words *have sustained* is already past perfect without *had* in the phrase.

Answer (score -1):

Correct Sentence is:

"The cargo was visible through the gap and was noted to have sustained damage"

In addition to this sentence:
He was working hard to have won the match.

Comment: Please indicate why you think so.

Comment: Thanks, but why is 'to had sustained damage" wrong (use of past perfect to define one event happening before another)